# geometry node distance used to measure distance between faces

Tags: geometry-nodes, extrude

Hi everyoby it’s first time i use geometry nodes so i’m trying to learn something; to do this i’m doing some experiments to better understand behaviour of each node and i’m stuck on a probably simple step that i don’t understand.
As shown in pictures i’m trying to see in viewer the distance between original face and the extruded one but i’m doing something wrong cause it returns the value of 1.732 instead the measured one (0.826572) and if i change the scale offset value in extrude GN it doesn’ change. where am i wrong?

thanks

[image]

Comment: I do not understand how do you define the *Distance*. It is mixing a Boolean (the *Top* output socket of the *Extrude Mesh* node), with a Null vector (the *Attribute* output socket of the *Capture Attribute* node with *Value* set to 0). This attribute is in the *Face* domain and the *Viewer* node is in the *Point* domain. It looks like a mess for me...

Comment: About the 0 or 1.732 value displayed in the Spreadsheet viewer, it will be a constant whatever is done because: the *Top* socket is returning 0 or 1 (Boolean) ; connected to a vector, it is transformed to (0,0,0) or (1,1,1) ; the Capture Attribute node is returning 0, which is connected to a vector, so it is (0,0,0) ; the *Distance* node is computing the distance between (0,0,0) and { (0,0,0) or (1,1,1) } ; this value is 0 or square root of 3 (i.e. 1.732). QED

Answer (score 0):

I can see two sources of confusion:

1. The [Capture Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/capture_attribute.html)-node is not "capturing" anything.
2. The geometry that the Capture Attribute-node is modifying is not what is being used in the subsequent steps.

In the image below I "capture" the position of the faces by connecting a [Position](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/read/position.html)-node to the Capture Attribute-node and then compare it to the extruded face's position (using an [Evaluate on Domain](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/field/evaluate_on_domain.html)-node).

[image: Geometry node group comparing the distance of face positions before and after an extrude mesh opperation]

Comment: thanks for your reply. You're right it's a few days since i started to work on GN and i'm trying to understand how they work; it's not so easy without any reference and i'm still a little bit confused. I'll take your solution and i'll try to understand it. Also i'll search a course on Geometry Nodes to learn the foundamental. again thank you very much!